# Android Material Components theme - change color of TextInputLayout/TextInputEditText label and underline when field is focused

Tags: android, material-design

I'm trying to switch to the new Material Components theme and the one thing I can't seem to change is the TextInputLayout/TextInputEditText color for the label and underline when the field is focused.

When I was using the AppCompat theme it used colorAccent for this, but the new MaterialComponents theme uses colorPrimary.

How do I override the MaterialComponents theme to use colorAccent just for this scenario?

Things I have tried:

- extending the Widget.MaterialComponents style for both TextInputLayout 
  and TextInputEditText and overriding colorPrimary
- extending the Widget.MaterialComponents style for both TextInputLayout 
  and TextInputEditText and overriding colorAccent
- Using a selector color for the backgroundTint on the TextInputEditText

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first define new theme - like this for example:

```
<style name="Theme2" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/holo_green_dark</item>
</style>
```

...then use it like this:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/filter_box_hint"
    android:theme="@style/Theme2">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/etFilter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/Theme2" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Result (pls ignore box, it's part of diff story) :

[image]

Comment: I needed theme on both TextInputLayout and TextInputEditText and I needed to override colorPrimary instead of colorAccent, but the general concept worked.  Thanks!

Comment: For me it was colorAccent)

Answer (score 0):

Without defining a new theme you can use:

```
app:boxStrokeColor="@color/colorAccent"
```